# Python 3 default value for datacalasses wont work together with property

Tags: python, python-3.7

Why won't property work for me, when I don't specify procent it throw me an exception (could it be a bug?)? or is it something that I'm missing with dataclasses?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class A(object):
    index: int
    #procent: float = 1.0
    procent: float = field(default=1.0)
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.row, self.col = divmod(self.index, 13)  # Row, Column

@dataclass
class B(object):
    index: int
    #procent: float = 1.0
    procent: float = field(default=1.0)
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.row, self.col = divmod(self.index, 13)  # Row, Column
    @property
    def procent(self):
        return self._procent
    @procent.setter
    def procent(self, x: float, base: float = 5):
        self._procent = float(base * round(x * 100 / base) / 100)


print(A(index=1, procent=0.33))
# A(index=1, procent=0.33)
print(A(1))
# A(index=1, procent=1.0)

print(B(1, 0.33))
# B(index=1, procent=1.35)

B(1) # Explodes here

#    self._procent = float(base * round(x * 100 / base) / 100)
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'property' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing the value in `self._procent`, you should also name your field `_procent`.

```
_procent: float = field(default=1.0)
```

In the context of the full example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class B(object):
    index: int
    _procent: float = field(default=1.0)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.row, self.col = divmod(self.index, 13)  # Row, Column

    @property
    def procent(self):
        return self._procent

    @procent.setter
    def procent(self, x: float, base: float = 5):
        self._procent = float(base * round(x * 100 / base) / 100)

print(B(1))
```

Output

```
B(index=1, _procent=1.0)
```